# How do I make the battery indicator always show my laptop battery by default instead of the mouse battery?

Tags: 14.04, indicator, battery, notification-area

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

If I plug in my USB wireless Logitech mouse (M185) it will show its battery status instead of the laptop's battery, but only when the laptop is plugged in. The battery level of the mouse isn't very useful to me, and I'd rather see the laptop battery's charge level and time remaining until full instead. I'd even go as far as just disabling the mouse battery indicator entirely if it fixes the issue.

How do I fix this? There isn't anything in the settings or the tweak tool.

Answer (score 1):

I remember this being fixed in one of the later releases. I'm on 15.04 right now and the battery always indicates the laptop battery, never the mouse.

You can try to upgrade to 15.10, however this might be a less stable release than 14.04. You can wait until the next lts: 16.04, (april 2016) to upgrade...

Comment: Huh. Strange thing is that it only happens when my laptop is plugged in to power. If I unplug it and run from battery, the laptop battery is shown. Kinda seems intentional. I'll try 15.10.

Comment: OK, so I tried 15.10, and it still didn't fix it. The mouse battery still shows up by default when the laptop is plugged in.

Comment: I had the same behavior a few releases back... I guess they figured it wasnt a good default behavior, so they changed it..

Comment: That is very strange, this is not the case anymore with my mouse, but it was a while back. Is it possible the battery of your mouse is very low? Maybe that's why it shows the mouse... Try putting in new batteries and see if that fixes it..

Comment: No, the batteries are fresh. Have only been using this mouse for a week.

Comment: Ok, so today, after restarting my computer I see the mouse battery again. I see that my laptop battery is full at the moment. Is it possible that the laptop battery is only shown if unplugged or not fully charged? Do you still see the mouse battery when laptop battery is at 70% and charging? This is rather strange behavior. Feel free to open a bug on launchpad and link it here...

Answer (score 0):

in my case on Ubuntu 16.04 and Unity desktop the solution was to go in settingds > power and to chose: "show battery status in the menu bar":"when battery is present". That made my mouse battery show up there altough my laptop battery was not showing at this time because I was on wire and batter was fully charged.